# Como atualizar uma página após insert, update ou delete com ajax sem reflesh

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tenho o código em página extena `delete.php` que faz as ações,

HTML:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAddfoto" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Adicionar Foto</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="addfoto" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                                <div class="col col-lg-3">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="datavisita">Data Vísita</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col col-lg-6">    
                                    <input type="text" name="dtvisita" id="dtvisita" required autocomplete="off" class="form-control  form-control-sm form-group small" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                                <div class="col col-lg-3">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="idvisita">Visíta</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class='col col-md-6'>   
                                    <input type="text" name="idvisita" id="idvisita" readonly class="form-control  form-control-sm form-group small" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                                <div class="col col-lg-3">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="percentandamento">Porcentagem Andamento</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col col-md-6 slidecontainer">
                                    <input type="range" name="percentandamento" id="percentandamento" required min="1" max="100" value="1" class="form-control-range slider" oninput="disp.value = percentandamento.value">
                                    <output  id="disp"></output>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                                <div class="col col-lg-3">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="caminhofoto">Foto</label>
                                </div>
                                <div>   
                                    <input type="file" name="caminhofoto" id="caminhofoto" required class="form-control-file form-control-sm form-group small" accept="image/png,image/jpg" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row justify-content-md-left">
                                <div class="col col-lg-3">
                                    <label class="control-label" class="control-label" for="descricaofoto">Descrição Foto</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class='col-md-auto'>                
                                    <textarea name="descricaofoto" id="descricaofoto" cols="25" rows="3" class="form-control  form-control-sm form-group small" ></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
         <div class="container">
         <!--getData.php-->
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Decrição Foto</th>
            <th>Data Visita</th>    
            <th>Andamento</th>
            <th>Foto</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Teste 01</td>
                    <td>18/10/2018</td>
                    <td>60%</td>
                    <td><img src="<?php print($row['caminhofoto']); ?>" alt="Imagem" height="42" width="42"></td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a id="delfoto" data-id="<?php echo $row['idfoto'] ?>"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

         </div>
```

No meu código js tenho:
o `getData.php` que faz a consulta ao banco e exibe uma tabela com os dados retornados

```
fetchUser();
function fetchUser()
{
    $.get("getData.php", function (data, status) {

    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    });
}
```

No caso do delete,

```
$("#delfoto").click(function () {
    id = $(this).data("id");
    alert(id);
    $.get("delete.php?id=" + id, function (data, status) {

    }).done(function (data) {
        fetchUser();
    });
});
```

no caso do delete `<a id="delfoto" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>` O problema é que como ele chama uma pagina externa para exibir os dados na div `result` então fica no código html do navegador vazio, como se não existisse, e ao tentar exluir um registro clicando no icon do link `id="delfoto"` nada ocorre justamente porque é como se não existisse esse cógido na pagina.

Eu gostaria de saber se há alguma outra forma de fazer atualização dos dados após uma ação CRUD ou se há como corrigir essa sem reflesh.

Comment: Você pode apenas remover o item que quiser, ou recarregar os dados, caso os mesmo sejam carregados via ajax, dentro da função done do ajax: `$('#item_a_deletar').remove()`

Comment: poderia dar um exemplo por favor,
Sei pouco de ajax com jquery.

Comment: Edita a pergunta adicionando seu HTML, por favor.

Comment: pronto, Editado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisando melhor sua pergunta percebi o que tem acontecido: Como seu link é adicionado após a inicialização da página ele não possui o event listener que é adicionado logo na inicialização e necessário para a ação. Mas você pode usar um elemento estático da página para adicionar o evento.

A sua função chamada pelo click ficaria:

```
$("body").on('click','#delfoto', function () {
  // a partir da versão 1.7 + pode-se usar também:
  // $('#delfoto').live( 'click', function () {

    id = $(this).data("id");
    alert(id);
    $.get("delete.php?id=" + id, function (data, status) {

    }).done(function (data) {
        fetchUser();
    });
});
```

Mais informações nos links:

https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements
https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: Muito obrigado,
Deu certo, me ajudou e muito.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou, até mais!